# I want to block USB Port using C# console application

Tags: c#, usb, registry, console-application

I am trying to make a simple program that can modify windows registry through code.I have tried adding an Application Manifest File to provide admin privileges to the code but nothing seems to work.

```
    try
        { 
            RegistryKey MyKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/USBSTOR", true);
         //the control jumps to catch after the above line.
            MyKey.SetValue("Start", "4", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Port locked");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }//throws a nullvaluerefrence exception
        catch
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("There was an error");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyKey.SetValue` has an invalid parameter. `string` cannot be converted to `int`.

```
MyKey.SetValue("Start", "4", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Change the code to:

```
MyKey.SetValue("Start", 0x4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: I have already tried changing escape sequence and still get the same result. The code jumps to catch block. Even the code you sent give same result.

Comment: @Hussain_prophetX Worked it out, it's because `"4"` cannot be converted to `int`.